# An Error Was Encountered Unable to send email using PHP mail(). Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp, gmail

I'm trying to sending an email using CodeIgniter via Gmail SMTP but the function is not working it is showing me this error on the localhost?

```
An Error Was Encountered Unable to send email using PHP mail(). 
Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
```

**Here my email function**

```
$config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => '******@gmail.com', // change it to yours
        'smtp_pass' => '**********', // change it to yours
        'mailtype' => 'html',
        'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
        'wordwrap' => TRUE
    );

    $message = 'Test';
    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from('*********@gmail.com'); // change it to yours
    $this->email->to('test@gmail.com');// change it to yours
    $this->email->subject('Resume from JobsBuddy for your Job posting');
    $this->email->message($message);
    if($this->email->send())
    {
        echo 'Email sent.';
    }
    else
    {
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }
```

Comment: most of host admins, prevent ```mail()``` function, you can try something like ```smtp```

Comment: @AKiani  but I have to try the same code on the different Codeigniter application it is working fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use PHP MAILER or SWIFT MAILER

- https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer
- https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer

---

For now here is PHPMAILER

```
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      //Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
    //$mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'sender@gmail.com';                     //SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'sender-password';                               //SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         //Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged                                   //TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    //TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('receiver1@gmail.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('receiver2@gmail.com', 'Dylan');     

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

You can install these amazing libarries  with composer